Определите количество восьмизначных чисел, записанных в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления, в записи которых ровно 3 чётные цифры
Правильный ответ: 895483904. Объясните, пожалуйста, как получить это число на бумаге или кодом.

Добро пожаловать на сайт, Илья Просекин, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Количество перестановок с повторением, и перемножить.

3 четные, значит, 5 нечетных. Берем учебник по комбинаторике и ищем нужную формулу.

Если число начинается с чётной цифры, то для неё есть 7 вариантов, не считая ноль. Остается 7 мест, на двух местах четные, значит, С(7,2) раскладов, и умножить на 8^2 - вариантов четных на двух местах, и 8^5 -
вариантов нечетных на пяти местах.
Аналогично считаем для первой нечетной цифры.
Итого:
7*C(7,2)*8^2*8^5 + 8*C(7,3)*8^3*8^4

